# DIV width illogically stuck and unable to change

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

[Here's a JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/9yjpc6u9/)

That there is a simple `<div>`. Inside it, there are another 2 `<divs>` and a `<h2>`. It's pretty simple. I have the width of the lower `<div>`—the *Google Maps* one(although it doesn't work in JSFiddle)—exactly the same as the width its parent `<div>`. It used to work perfectly. I don't really remember when, but I'm sure that before adding my `<h2>` and a couple of modifications(maybe?), it was as wide as it was supposed to be.
 Now, it's stuck at that stupid width—although the *Maps* still works—no matter what I do.

---

I tried removing the `<h1>` tag to see if that was the problem, but nothing was fixed. I also tried numerous other things, but I just can't get that `<div>` return to its rightful width.

---

Here's the code for if you want to see it here instead of on JSFiddle:
*HTML & JavaScript*(although *JavaScript* may not matter as it doesn't affect size of the `<div>`):

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.726371, 44.731433),
    zoom: 18,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
};
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
 #wrap-left {
   float: left;
   border: 1px solid black;
   margin-top: 60px;
   font-family: TikalSansMedium;
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
   font-size: 11pt;
   background-color: white;
   border: 1px solid #9F9F9F;
   border-radius: 2px;
   height: 450px;
   width: 610px;
   position: relative;
 }
 h2#fnd_cl {
   border: 1px solid #9F9F9F;
   border-radius: 2px;
   position: absolute;
   top: -33px;
   left: 30%;
   font-family: 'Antic Slab';
   background-color: #F8CE26;
   width: 230px;
   text-align: center;
 }
 div#cont {
   height: 50px;
   padding-left: 8px;
   padding-top: 35px;
   border: 1px solid black;
 }
 div#map-canvas {
   width: 610px;
   height: 300px;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 230px;
   background-color: black;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<br>

<div id="wrap-left">

  <h2 id="fnd_cl">Find or Call us</h2>

  <div id="cont">
    Our workshop is located on Blah-blah Street.
    <br />Call us on: 556-546-564 or 2-35-68-91
  </div>

  <div id="map-canvas"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: There are two "width" rules in your div#map-canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `width:230px;` from `div#map-canvas`

You declared width twice in this block of CSS which is causing your issue.

Comment: Oh. Well, that was... stupid.
Can't understand how I missed _that_ out of all things.
Well, thanks.

Comment: It can happen to the best of us sometimes. :)